# Database design: Deciding primary key for country, state, city tables

Tags: database-design, primary-key

I have designed 3 tables as below:

**Table**: Country

Columns:

- country(name of country),
- iso2_code,
- iso3_code,
- phone_code

**primary key**: country

**Table**: State

Columns:

- state(name of state),
- country(fk from country table)

**primary key**: state, country

**Table**: City

Columns:

- city(name of city),
- state(fk),
- country(fk)

**primary key**: city, state, country

I have used composite keys as primary key for state & city tables.
Is it bad design?
Should I create auto-increment key for state & city tables & use them as primary key?

Comment: Be careful with the PK on City. Sometimes there can be more than one combination. Simcoe, Ontario in Canada is a good example, as there are two of them several hundred km apart

Comment: @matigo, yes there can be two state or two city with same name. That is why I have kept primary key as city+state+country.

Comment: @mustaccio, composite primary keys bad practice does not give clear answer to above question because it says it depends on case by case we should either go with composite key & for some we should not but I am not sure for above case.

Comment: Even with city+state+country, you’d be looking at Simcoe+ON+CA twice; one that is just north of Lake Erie, and the other is darn near by James Bay